# Nonlinear GMM for Dynamic Panel Data

Tags: panel-data, nonlinear, generalized-moments, dynamic-regression

A friend of mine needs to estimate a non-linear GMM on Panel data. As I have checked, the softwares for Panel GMM only estimate linear forms (STATA gmm, xtabond, ...; R pgmm from plm package). How can I do nonlinear Dynamic Panel GMM estimation?

Comment: What kind of individual effects do you want tot take into account? If the answer is few or none, you can use a standard gmm function. If it's more than that you're likely going to have to program parts of it yourself.